# Sql query to return one row per customer

Tags: mysql

This is for pizza order sample database and Column names  are Customerid,Orderdate, Orderid,Orderitemid,cancelled,size,toppings. When trying to get result for one row per customer with columns customerid,First order date, total pizza orders and whether any pizzas Orders are cancelled. I am getting this result for this code

```
Select customerid
     , min(orderdate) as first order date
     , case when cancelled = ‘N‘
          then count(orderid) else 0 end as total pizza orders
     , case when cancelled = ‘Y’ 
          then ‘Yes’ else ‘No‘ End as cancelled orders  
  from Orders 
 group 
    by customerid;
```

I am getting same customerid thrice with first order date, second order date and third.

Also for this same customerid when in first order date if he has both cancelled and delivered orders, I am not getting that cancelled order.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and [mre] and edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to `group by customerid`. Also, your count logic should go inside the aggregate functions, like:

```
SELECT customerid,
   min(orderdate) AS FIRST ORDER date, 
   count(*) AS total_orders,
   count(CASE 
            WHEN cancelled='Y' 
            THEN 1
            END) AS cancelled_orders
FROM orders o
WHERE to_days(orderdate)=
    (SELECT min(to_days(orderdate))
     FROM orders
     WHERE customerid=o.customerid)
GROUP BY customerid
```

> EDIT: Added a where clause per your comments

Comment: When We use count(*), I am getting all orders of that customer but I want only orders in first order date. Also, I want orders that are cancelled in first order date. If a customer has 3 order same order items( 3 orders) on first order date and cancelled one, then I should get that customer too.

Comment: I misunderstood. If you only care about the customer's first order you'll need to restrict your results in the where clause

Comment: It worked. Thank you!